# Google for rails - Google Maps use local API javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails on my project. This gem works amazing but i have a question and could not find the answer on github wiki.

The problem is everytime that the page is loaded, the gem send request to the google maps javascript api. There is any way to download this js files and config the gem to use this and not downloaded every request ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, to use the Google Maps API, you must load the bootstrap from Google servers.